# How do I show N divs every time user clicks same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, show

Let's suppose we have 18 divs but only 4 of them are visible, below a "see more" button. I'd like to show the next 4 divs when user clicks this button, and repeat this process until there is no more divs to display. Is it possible?
I wasn't able to find the answer and to solve it either.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML / javascript showing what you've tried so far?  Perhaps via [jsfiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .slice

Working Example with JQuery Selectors
https://jsfiddle.net/duf9xcyz/

This will allow you to only select the first 4 items from the jquery selector

```
$('div:hidden').slice(0,4).show();
```

https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: This will just show the first 4 divs.. does nothing to help OP with their problem.

Comment: added the hidden selector which should take care of that issue

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hCXdkiJQhihkHG9VIl3?p=preview) is a working example for you. Basically, on click you just need to remove hidden class on the div.

```
$(function(){
  $("#showMore").on("click", function() {
      var hiddenDivs = $('div.hidden');
      if (hiddenDivs.length > 0) {
        hiddenDivs.slice(0,4).removeClass('hidden');  
      }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may create the div(s) as the 'see more' button is clicked using jquery. or you may have all the divs in html but marked 14 of them with 'display:none' and onclick of 'see more' button you may use jquery to toggle next 4 as the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could do something like this:

```
        var allDivs = $('div'),
            counter = 4; //initial number of divs displayed

        var showDivs = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) {
                if (counter === allDivs.length) {
                    console.log('All divs are displaying');
                    break;
                }
                $(allDivs[counter]).show();
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        };
        $('#aButton').click(showDivs);
```